# When are selectionWillChange: and selectionDidChange: called?

Tags: ios

I am developing custom keyboard extension in iOS, and I'm wondering when the two `UITextInputDelegate` methods (`selectionWillChange:` and `selectionDidChange:`) called? Has someone tried to implement these two methods and made them work?

Answer (score 0):

According to [this](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITextInputDelegate_Protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UITextInputDelegate/textDidChange:)
selection did change is called when the user takes the current highlighted text and replaces the whole thing or part of it.  The selection will change is what it is going to change into before the did change event is fired.